# Keep the clicked article tracked / active using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm facing one issue with jQuery parent ul li open below is my html structure:

```
<div>
  <ul>
     <li class="has-sub">
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">1.1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">1.2</a></li>
           <li class="has-sub">
             <a href="#">2</a>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
                <li class="has-sub">
                  <a href="#">3</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">3.1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">3.2</a></li>
                      More...
                  </ul>
                </li>
             </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
  $('a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass('activation');
    }
  });
});
```

css:

```
.open > a:after,
.open > a:before {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
 transform: rotate(89deg);}
```

`activation` class add, but not open parent ul li.

I need which class is activation then this parent ul li open that time.

How can I reach this solution?

Comment: well it doesn't appear you're applying .open to anything.  So obviously it wouldn't work.  You need to add the class open to whatever you're trying to open.  Unless .activation has some opening code too.  You dont show that though, so I dont know

Comment: I added  `$(this).parent('ul').addClass('open');` but not working

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is what you were trying to ask:

```
$(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {

      $('li').removeClass('open');
      $('a').removeClass('activation');
      $(this).addClass('activation').closest("li").addClass("open");
    }
  });
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tkbejtfz/)

Do check the structure via Inspect Element.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use following js :

```
$(function() {
  $('a').removeClass('activation');
  $('ul').removeClass('open');
  $('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == '#') { //replace your url
      $(this).addClass('activation');
      $(this).parent().parent().addClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```

Find working **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dipali_vasani/oLsmwrL8/3/)**

Comment: Not work, for information my default css is https://jsfiddle.net/oLsmwrL8/5/  I comment out after your js code, please see this

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dipali_vasani/oLsmwrL8/6/ check this. Is that what you need ?

Answer (score 0):

This is my final jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
  $('a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass('activation');
        $(this).parent().closest('.has-sub').addClass('open active');
    }
  });
});
```

But now work only second position not work 3rd or 4th position

css:

```
.active {
  display: block;
}
```